# Type Casting to reduce code

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to implement `memset()`. My code is functional but I want to know if my use of cast is a good or bad thing.

```
void* __memset(void *b, int c, size_t len){
    while (len--)
        *((unsigned char*)(b++)) = (unsigned char)c;
    return (b);
}
```

My code was longer but I decided to cast the `void*` to make it shorter. Is this okay or will the code break.

Comment: Why are you implementing memset?  It exists, use it

Comment: `C` or `C++`, please choose one

Comment: Arithmetic on a `void*` is a constraint violation in C.

Comment: Is there any good reason to "reduce" code (that compromises readability)?

Comment: Which cast? The first is essential, the second unnecessary.

Comment: And the return value is wrong, too.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus:I take it you're not familiar with `memset()`? C11 draft standard n1570: *7.24.6 Miscellaneous functions 7.24.6.1 The memset function 2 The memset function copies the value of c (converted to an unsigned char) into each of the first n characters of the object pointed to by s.* The cast to `unsigned char` here is not incorrect. It is of course also unnecessary.

Comment: **Why** do you want to make your code shorter?  So it can be harder to understand and more bug-prone?

Comment: memset is a builtin operation in gcc and clang. Why are we re-writing it? The implementation of it is going to be implementation-defined. For example, the x86 versions pad out the ends of the area with bytes but fill the middle with dword (or even XMM) writes.

Comment: @RichardHodges The loop here is simple enough that gcc and clang should auto-vectorize it even if it wasn't a builtin.

Comment: @EOF I decided to test your theory on clang. Compiled the function with `-O3`. And sorry to say, it didn't auto-vectorize it. Instead, it called `memset`.

Comment: @user3386109 we had the same idea - see my answer. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for code review and so belongs on the [Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 2):

Warning (and this is actually quite amusing):

Redeclaring standard names is a bad idea because it invokes 'undefined behaviour'. This is not just some woolly concept. It's *really bad* because the compiler makes decisions on the assumption that you won't invoke undefined behaviour.

Consider this c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void* memset(void *b, int c, size_t len){
  unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)b;
  while (len--) {
    *p++ = c;
  }
  return b;
}
```

now compile with `gcc5.3 -O3`:

Yields this assembler code:

```
memset:
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        je      .L6
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movzbl  %sil, %esi
        call    memset
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
.L6:
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        ret
```

Result: BOOM!

Comment: Yup, I had to laugh when I saw the code that clang generated. Same thing, you do all this work to rewrite the function, and the compiler just calls the built-in function anyways, LOL. Except now it's even better, with infinite recursion.

Comment: Many compilers will recognize patterns that resemble memset (and other key functions) and generate a function call.  This can be avoided in gcc with `-fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns`... otherwise, you'd never be able to write a generic memset in C without using inline assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `b` is of type `(void*), then`b++` is not even valid C or C++ code. So it is a 100% bad thing, since the code will not compile on a standard compliant compiler.

Note that for example gcc has a non-standard extension allowing arithmetic on void pointers. You can turn gcc into a standard compliant compiler with the correct compiler options:

`gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

The typical implementation of memset in C would otherwise look like this:

```
void* memset(void* s, int c, size_t n)
{
  uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*) s;

  while(n != 0)
  {
    *ptr = (uint8_t)c;
    ptr++;
    n--;
  }

  return s;
}
```

And no, don't try to make it an icky one-liner mess. Write readable code. The produced binary will be identical anyhow.

(This code assumes that any sane compiler will treat `uint8_t` as a character type, for pointer aliasing purposes.)

Comment: `uint8_t` is not guaranteed to be a character type. Stick with `unsigned char`.

Comment: @EOF I was adding that side-note in an edit just as you posted the comment :) I know there is no such guarantee in the standard, but a compiler which doesn't treat `uint8_t` as a character type is hopelessly broken and practically useless anyway. Might be better to expose that the compiler is useless, rather than adapting your code for compatibility with useless compilers.

Comment: Is there any reason *not* to use `unsigned char`? I can't see any downside.

Comment: Why not use unsigned char and be completely portable?

Comment: @EOF Various subtle stuff. A `char` might have more than 8 bits. `char` types may insane signedness formats while stdint types are guaranteed to have sane two's complement format. And then there's the whole mess with the design flaw of the C language which allows implementation-defined signedness of `char`. Therefore it is good practice to stay away from `char` entirely, unless you are using it for strings. It will also make the code MISRA-C compatible.

Comment: @Lundin EOF is suggesting unsigned char not char.

Comment: @Lundin: We're not talking about `char`, we're talking about `unsigned char`, which is also guaranteed to be be pure binary without padding bits ("sane two's complement"). If `unsigned char` has more than eight bits, `uint8_t` won't even exist.

Comment: @2501 Yes but you should keep your coding style consistent. Using `uint8_t` in some situations and `unsigned char` in other situations would make your code inconsistent.

Comment: At any rate, it doesn't matter for this question. By all means use `unsigned char` if it makes you happy. The actual reason I used it here is because the code was a copy-paste from a MISRA-compliant std lib I have written.

Answer (score 0):

How about reducing the code and reaping the benefits of a generic function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void *g_memset(void *dst, size_t dstSize, void *val, size_t valSize);

int main(void)
{
    int val = 4;
    int dst[5];

    size_t valSize = sizeof(val);
    size_t dstSize = sizeof(dst) / sizeof(dst[0]);

    g_memset(dst, dstSize, &val, sizeof(val));

    for (size_t n = 0; n < dstSize; n++) {
        printf("%d ", dst[n]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}


void *g_memset(void *dst, size_t dstSize, void *val, size_t valSize)
{
    char *ptr = (char *)dst;
    while (dstSize-- > 0) {
        memcpy(ptr, val, valSize);
        ptr += valSize;
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: Because OP is trying to reinvent the standard C library, and that's not how the `memset` function is defined.

Comment: @user3386109 I'll keep it for my self then :)

Comment: @EOF i renamed it to `g_memset`.Are you happy now?